# PrincipalContext Access Denied After encountering Unresolved SID

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, active-directory

Working with ASP.NET / VB.NET

I'm writing a series of tools that allows users/managers to view various information about which users have which access on various PCs and Servers across the network.  At first, I had an issue enumerating lists of users in a group containing Unresolved SIDS (I know -- we should be pulling these out, and we will be.  One benefit of the tool I'm writing is that it emails IT Helpdesk to inform them of the URSID).  I was able to get past this problem with some try/catch and manually enumerating through the list (It's ugly..)-- creating a fresh list of users that doesn't include the URSIDs.

So, for a single system -- I might check the access rights on multiple groups.  Here's my new problem:
For System X -- If I get users from GroupA which contains an URSID, I can complete the operation for GroupA (obtain users/enumerate through URSIDs/report users).  However, when my code loops back and tries to obtain users from GroupB for System X (reusing the same PrincipalContext object OR using a new PrinicipalContext object mapped to the same PC), I get an Access Denied error.

Notes:  I am specifying a service account to connect with, and the service account has the correct permissions.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening, or any ideas of how to resolve/catch/work around the issue?

## Code Summary here:

```
Using DBCon As New WebServicesDBEntities
        Dim SysDB As ObjectSet(Of Systems) = DBCon.Systems1
        Dim SysList = From Sys In SysDB _
                      Where (Sys.Location_Name = Location)
                      Select New With {.Name = Sys.Name}

        'Loop through each system and populate the table.
        For Each Sys In SysList

            'Build the system context.  Uses custom function that returns PrincipalContext object from string.
            Dim sysCtx As PrincipalContext = GetSystemPrincipalContext(Sys.Name)

            'Capture the system is offline in the error table and loop to next.
            If IsNothing(sysCtx) Then
    /etc
            Else

                'Get applicable groups for the system.
                Using ctx As New WebServicesDBEntities
                    Dim Accesses As ObjectSet(Of Access) = ctx.Accesses
                    Dim Groups = From Group In Accesses _
                                 Where (Group.System_Name = Sys.Name) _
                                 Select New With {.Name = Group.Group, _
                                                  .level = Group.Level}

                    'Loop through each group and obtain a list of users in each group.

                    For Each Group In Groups

                        'Get a list of users in the group.
                        Dim Users As New Collections.Generic.List(Of UserPrincipal)
                        Dim GrpCtx As GroupPrincipal = GetGroupPrincipal(Group.Name, sysCtx)
                        Dim result As Integer = GetUsersInGroup(GrpCtx, Users)


                        If result = 0 Then
    'Error obtaining users 
                        Else
                            'Report Users here
                        End If

                        Users.Clear()
                        GrpCtx.Dispose()
                    Next

                End Using

            End If
            sysCtx.Dispose()
        Next

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code relevant to this question - that will help us help you better!

Comment: I added the main component of the code -- I can post any individual functions if you'd like.  When this code looks at a system with no URSIDs, everything works fine.  The Sysctx object is the object that will show "Access Denied" after encountering the URSID.